# error while build iOS app in Xcode : Sandbox: rsync.samba (13105) deny(1) file-write-create, Flutter failed to write to a file

Tags: ios, flutter, xcode, macos, build

while building iOS app on Xcode I got these 2 errors, I tried to build the iOS on visual studio code and I got the same errors. the operating system macOS 14.0 beta. processor M1 Pro

[image: errors messages]

Could downgrading the operating system fix that issue?

Answer (score 557, accepted):

Update your Xcode project build option `ENABLE_USER_SCRIPT_SANDBOXING` to 'No'.

[image]

Comment: Not only the correct answer, but probably the only reference to the correct answer on the internet. Could use some more context and screen shots though.

Comment: this is indeed the correct answer. but why is this needed at all?

Comment: Best answer found on the internet

Comment: I ran into this as a result of updating the project settings for Xcode 15 (I accepted the recommended changes - lol).

Comment: rsync 9974 and rsync 9987 went away, but now I have errors for rsync 10090 and 10093 which say:
Sandbox: rsync(10090) deny(1) file-write-create /Users/jonathan/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Go_Cart-cfpedjquevfpxzaopshdpjedieco/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/XCFrameworkIntermediates/Realm/Headers

Comment: I have set this to NO and same as @jonathan3087 I still have similar errors ..
Sandbox: rsync(37912) deny(1) file-write-create /Users/plasma/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/RTSPtest-fjamhnfxeyhjfjabnbhpcrctfmth/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/XCFrameworkIntermediates/MobileVLCKit/dSYMs
Sandbox: rsync(37913) deny(1) file-write-create /Users/plasma/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/RTSPtest-fjamhnfxeyhjfjabnbhpcrctfmth/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/XCFrameworkIntermediates/MobileVLCKit/MobileVLCKit.framework/.MobileVLCKit.izJrf5

Comment: @Cesar XCode 15 introduces new 'sandboxing' feature, and recommends it to us in yellow warning mark. Going along with it is detrimental to flutter development however, because 'sandboxing' limits our app's interaction with the OS and access to our storage, which is important in development stage. Sandboxing is only useful for production, IMHO, to protect end user from evil apps. I don't know what where XCode's makers thinking.

Comment: @DanielWu any idea why this flag has been introduced? I fixed the issue with the answer, but I want to know why this came up.

Comment: There will be a day that XCode will launch a new version with full backward compatibility (no breaks at all!!!)... but I think our Lord Jesus will come back first!!

Comment: @Michael breaking compatibility on each version release is Apple's policy

Comment: Update your Xcode project build option ENABLE_USER_SCRIPT_SANDBOXING to 'No'. this solution is working for me.

Comment: I wonder when users can sandbox again.

Comment: Forget Chat GPT; I went down the rabbit hole for 4 hours. Finally googled and this fixed it immediately.

Comment: @WhoDis Give a shot to perplexity.ai, I got here just throwing the error on its prompt. This tool references its answers.

Comment: There's no other way to say it: please *do not* trust any apple-related update. It *will* break your projects.

Comment: @venir hear hear!

Comment: I guess you are part of the XCode team, otherwise I can't imagine how did you figure this out :)

Answer (score 53):

@hasayakey 's answer worked for me, but I wanted to add some extra info about how to find this setting.

To find the 'ENABLE_USER_SCRIPT_SANDBOXING' go to the Search icon tab in the left hand panel within Xcode. Ensure you are searching within the 'Runner' workspace, configured the search to ignore text and then press enter to search with text 'ENABLE_USER_SCRIPT_SANDBOXING'.

In Xcode 14/15, the result should look like this:

[image: Xcode Search Tab]

Alternatively, you can navigate to this setting by going to:

Xcode > Project > Runner > Build Settings > Build Options > User Script Sandboxing (near the bottom of build options)

[image: Xcode 15 User Script Sandboxing Location]

Comment: Anyone know if the App Review folks will flag this fix?

Comment: @ICL1901 I have had this setting in multiple app store releases now and it has been fine.

Answer (score 17):

ENABLE_USER_SCRIPT_SANDBOXING = NO

Search **ENABLE_USER_SCRIPT_SANDBOXING** and if it shows yes then disable it
[image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vb6zS.png)

and this worked for me

Answer (score 9):

The answers didn't work for me because I had two targets. `Runner`, and `Flutter Assemble`. I had never seen the latter before, so I switched `ENABLE_USER_SCRIPT_SANDBOXING` to 'No' for them both, and it worked.

[image]

Answer (score 8):

Sadly, simply turning it off (setting to No) doesn't fix issues for my Flutter project.

Got another set of similar errors.

I got solution following these:

1. Set `User Script Sandboxing` to `No` from Project->Build Settings
2. Exit Xcode
3. Flutter clean, then Flutter pub get
4. run `pod install` from terminal (inside *ios* folder)

Answer (score 2):

In my case, after integration of Cleverpush SDK, I got the issue.

In the iOS project, in the XCode I had to do the next steps:

1. Tap on 'Runner' in the tree on the left toolbar;
2. Select 'CleverPushNotificationServiceExtension' in the 'targets' list;
3. Select 'Building Settings' element on the columns;
4. Select 'All' & 'Combined';
5. Filter by 'ENABLE_USER_SCRIPT_SANDBOXING' keyword;
6. Set the 'User Script Sandboxing' parameter to 'No'.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Caution:
While setting ENABLE_USER_SCRIPT_SANDBOXING to NO might resolve the immediate issue, it's crucial to understand that this might expose your app and users to potential security vulnerabilities. Sandboxing is a critical security feature that prevents scripts from accessing or modifying data and resources they shouldn't.

Comment: was there any generative AI involved in the writing of this answer?

Comment: What  does `ENABLE_USER_SCRIPT_SANDBOXING` do?

Comment: Dude.. we are the developer. We are the one who wrote the codes we are about to test run. What are we gonna do to our own mac? We are not silly enough to download and run some codes from some shady websitfes.

Comment: so @skyluke, what is the recommended solution?

Comment: Looks like a ChatGPT Answer

Answer (score 0):

I were stuck with the same issue
have a solution for some one who uses CocoaPods as Package manager:
To resolve properly without set ENABLE_USER_SCRIPT_SANDBOXING = No, first you need to comment in the Podfile the command "use_frameworks!", i.e. leaving it out (in this way you be able to set in Build Phases -> Link Binary with Libraries the libPods-namePod.a instead of namePod.framework) then run pod install and finally build and run,
enjoy!