# Xcode 15: cp - Operation not permitted

Tags: xcode, shell

My project won't build on Xcode 15. This is happening both locally on my machine and on Xcode Cloud.

I've got a Build Phase script that I use to write my app secrets to the disk after fetching them from the CI.
Here's my script:

```bash
target_file="./MyProject/SupportingFiles/Secrets.json"

if [[ $CONFIGURATION == "Debug Development" || $CONFIGURATION == "Release Development" ]]; then
cp "./MyProject/SupportingFiles/SecretsDev.json" "$target_file"
echo "Wrote Dev secrets."
elif [[ $CONFIGURATION == "Debug Production" || $CONFIGURATION == "Release Production" ]]; then
cp "./MyProject/SupportingFiles/SecretsProd.json" "$target_file"
echo "Wrote Prod secrets."
fi
```

But when I build my project, I see this error in the build logs:

```
cp: ./MyProject/SupportingFiles/SecretsDev.json: Operation not permitted
Wrote Dev secrets.
```

It looks like that for some reason, Xcode 15 now enforces some kind of disk access restriction.

What can I do to make this script work in Xcode 15 in a way that will work both on my machine and also on Xcode Cloud?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

`ENABLE_USER_SCRIPT_SANDBOXING` needs to be no

same question here: [error while build iOS app in Xcode : Sandbox: rsync.samba (13105) deny(1) file-write-create, Flutter failed to write to a file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76590131/error-while-build-ios-app-in-xcode-sandbox-rsync-samba-13105-deny1-file-w)

Comment: It all makes sense seing the name of this option, but you've got to know it exists! Thank you, this is indeed the solution to make these scripts work 

Comment: I did not know this was even an option. At least did not know about it before Xcode 15. Thank you, this works.