Collecting FIXME and TODO:'s in XCode using a bash script
I did try to find an answer before, but keeps getting no results when putting the following in the script part of XCode.
Side note: in case of wondering, the purpose is that it searches only inside Objective-C and swift files.
I want to extent it but let me first get the basics right to understand how it works. I did try this script under 'Xcode 15.4', 'Xcode 16' and 'Xcode 16.1 beta 2' by adding a 'run script' script.
#!/bin/bash
# Enable debug mode to log the script steps
set -xe

# Use Xcode's environment variable to get the project directory (inside sandbox)
PROJECT_DIR="${SRCROOT}"

# Set the output file (correct concatenation)
OUTPUT_FILE="${PROJECT_DIR}/todo_fixme_report.txt"

# Ensure the script only searches within the project directory (avoiding external volumes)
grep -r --include=\*.{swift,m,h} -l "TODO:\|FIXME:" "$PROJECT_DIR" > "$OUTPUT_FILE"

# Check if grep encounters an error (e.g., no matching files found)
if [ $? -ne 0 ]; then
    echo "Error: Could not search files. Check if the directory is correct."
    exit 1
fi

# Check if the output file is not empty
if [ -s "$OUTPUT_FILE" ]; then
    echo "The following files contain TODOs or FIXMEs:" >> "$OUTPUT_FILE"
    grep -r --include=\*.{swift,m,h} "TODO:\|FIXME:" "$PROJECT_DIR" >> "$OUTPUT_FILE"
else
    echo "No TODOs or FIXMEs found." > "$OUTPUT_FILE"
fi

# Open the output file in Xcode without adding it to the project
open -a /Applications/Xcode-15.4.0.app "$OUTPUT_FILE" &

# Ensure the script exits successfully
exit 0

If I run this script in the terminal it works fine.
But in Xcode I get
Sandbox: bash(50795) deny(1) file-write-create /Volumes/Puddle/.../_Projects_Current/MyApp/todo_fixme_report.txt
But all the app's even Grep and Bash does have full disk access. The Puddle drive is the drive where the 'User' data live's.
What do I miss here?
Any suggestions appreciated.

You have to configure the output thru Xcode run script phase. Otherwise you are sandboxed.

please explain? I did also drag this run script as high as possible in the followup chain.

Before I did add $(SRCROOT)/todo_fixme_report.txt as an item in the 'output files' table; did get more error's

Yes, I see. Try this instead: https://stackoverflow.com/a/77143319/341994 Just turn off the script sandboxing and be done with it. :)

Thank you - that works now. One more thing I get with the line 'open -a Xcode-15.4.0 "$OUTPUT_FILE"' - "Command PhaseScriptExecution failed with a nonzero exit code
". My guess is that xcode gets open but never exists. How can I fix that?

It looks like I did fix it with a '&' after that line; I do update the question. But can I make it so that it calls the -running- xcode without any use of the full name or path?

Like Matt shows with the link found in his comments, you must to have

ENABLE_USER_SCRIPT_SANDBOXING

set to be no. You can find this under the 'Build Settings' tab. Filter 'User Script Sandboxing' or with a part of this text. Change it from 'YES' to 'No'.
Then no need to have Grep and Bash full access privileges.
===
If you want to start Xcode, you can use just 'Xcode' but then it opens the default Xcode version. If you want to open a specific Xcode version use the whole app name. Also if it stops running the script use the '&' at the end of the 'open' command line.
