# Xcode 15.0.1 | CocoaPods 1.14.2 : Build failed with error rsync: recv_generator: mkdir "/Users/.../_CodeSignature" failed: Operation not permitted

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, cocoapods, xcode15

I am using Xcode 15.0.1 with installed cocoapods 1.14.2 in Apple M1 chip. I was successfully able to install cocoapods using `brew install cocoapods`
I am able to run `pod install` in my project.
In Xcode 15 while running the build the project, I am getting the below errors -

Showing Recent Issues

> rsync: recv_generator: mkdir "/Users/../_CodeSignature" failed:
> Operation not permitted (1)
>
> *** Skipping everything below this failed directory ***
>
> rsync error: some files could not be transferred (code 23) at
> /AppleInternal/Library/BuildRoots/.../Sources/rsync/rsync/main.c(996)
> [sender=2.6.9]

Comment: Look at this answer, seems the same case: https://stackoverflow.com/a/76626156/1767388