# Having trouble archiving my Xcode project because of an "Invalid Run Destination"

Tags: ios, xcode, build, archive, build-error

I am currently trying to archive my Xcode project but whenever I try to, it gives me a popup error saying : "Invalid Run Destination: The current scheme doesn't have a run destination that can produce an archive." I am using the IPhone 15 pro rosetta simulator.

Running the project works as expected. It opens the iphone simulator and it opens my app. Please help me figure out what's going on.

Comment: Select the destination "Any iOS Device (arm64)".

Comment: i cant find that destination. all i see under the build section is "Any iOS simulator device (arm64, x86_64)"

Answer (score 6):

**There is a simple solution to this one.**

**First, select 'Any iOS device(arm64)' from the run destination,**

[image: select 'Any iOS device(arm64)']

**Then try archiving the project,**

[image: Archive]

Comment: i cant find that destination. all i see under the build section is "Any iOS simulator device (arm64, x86_64)"

Comment: Have you tried setting "Build Active Architecture Only (ONLY_ACTIVE_ARCH)" to Yes under the Build Settings -> Architectures?

Comment: This now gives me a different error: Sandbox: mkdir(23381) deny(1) file-write-create. Do you know what this error is?

Comment: Have you tried this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76590131/error-while-build-ios-app-in-xcode-sandbox-rsync-samba-13105-deny1-file-w) ?

Comment: this didn't give me anything useful, I have already set user sandboxing to 'no' as per your suggestion and the one person who had this error there wasn't responded to

Answer (score 0):

Check your target build settings. It should contain iOS (phones) as supported platform:

[image: iphoneios platform settings]

Then you should be able to select "Any iOS Device (arm64)" as a target device