Sandbox: rsync.samba(66985) deny(1) file-write-create
I clone project, working on android, but on ios when i run project its giving me multiple error related to Sandbox: rsync.samba(66985) deny(1) file-write-create.
I tried almost every solution. I also checked in Build Settings. In Build Options, set Ueer Script Sandboxing is already false.

I tried multiple times, but its still giving me
Sandbox: rsync.samba(66985) deny(1) file-write-create /Users/umairrehan/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Beams-fuarwsbxyqpmfgepcezmfhvxyesh/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/XCFrameworkIntermediates/Flipper-DoubleConversion/double-conversion.framework/Headers

try this https://stackoverflow.com/a/76626156/22000500

If you are using Xcode 15 or the latest code version try to set "No" for the "User Scripting sandbox" option on build Settings.
